# docker-compose.yml use volume on documents starting with dot (.)

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am using docker container with tomcat to run application. The application is saving some data in a folder that starts with dot(.). In the yml file I have something like this:

> volumes:
>        - /my/path/folder:/path/.* folder

It is saving the required folder on the disk, but when I'm starting again the container it doesn't persist what was saved on the disk. Is there a way to do this correctly? I prefer to not change the name of the folder.

Comment: Could you publish the entire yml file?

Comment: There should be nothing preventing a dot at the start of the volume path. Can you provide a [mcve]? The `*` in your volume definition here most likely won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm I have the same problem with docker-compose (1.22.0 on Fedora 29). Docker-compose doesn't seem to allow dotfiles in Volumes declaration.

This works in docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  - data:/root/folder
```

This does not:

```
volumes:
  - data:/root/.folder
```

Where both exist in the container. I've posted on docker hub and no one there seems to know either.